# Как правильно написать условие

Tags: java

Как написать условие при котором `if(w==(x&z)){......}`?
Чтобы условие выполнялось, `w` должно быть равно и `x`, и `z`. В данном случае, если `w` равно одной из переменных, а другой к примеру не равно, то условие становится `true`, а нужно только чтобы при равенстве всех переменных условие становилось `true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял,то:

```
if( (w==x) && (w==z) ){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(w==(x&z))
```

Так как `x&z` возвращает только `true` или `false`, значит `w` будет проверятся на наличие булевого значения и сравниваться с результатом выражения (`x&z`).

Если проверить все три значения, то как-то так:

```
int w=1,z=1,x=1;
boolean d = (w==x) && (w==z) ? true: false;
```